# Are tails of $L_1$ functions eventually bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a function $f \in L_1(\mathbb{R})$.

**My question is:** Are tails of $L_1$ functions eventually bounded?

In other words, can we show that for a given $f \in  L_1$ there exists an $x_0$ and $ c<\infty$ such that
\begin{align}
| f(x) | \le c, \forall x>x_0. 
\end{align}

Some thoughts:

It's not difficult to show that measure of the event
\begin{align} 
\{ |f(x)| >c\}  \cap \{x>x_0\} 
\end{align}
goes zero, but it's not quite what we want.   I also assume something like this was already asked here, but I could not located such a post.

Comment: At each positive integer $n$ put a "bump" of height $n$ and width $1/n^3$. That looks like a counterexample to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  counterexample would be
$$
f=\sum_n\,n\,1_{[n,n+1/n^3]}.
$$